# Ability to collapse "Tagged with" tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, custom-questions-list

With the ability to create custom filters that can comprise of many tags, it pushes results to below the fold when the page is loaded

[image]

Would be great if that tag cloud could be hidden/collapsed on demand if needed

Thoughts?

Comment: cross site dupe (MSE): [Provide an option to hide the list of tags in the custom filters display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330331/provide-an-option-to-hide-the-list-of-tags-in-the-custom-filters-display)